# How to address android lint complaint about exported Firebase Messaging service implementations?

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-lint

Following the [Google developer instructions on implementing Firebase in my app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), I notice that android lint complains.

The idea is that we have to implement two services which inherit from Firebase services:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService { ... }

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService { ... }
```

and then register those services in the manifest. But, it's not quite perfect. In particular, these two recommended AndroidManifest.xml service entries do not contain any special permissions:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and so the linter says:

> Exported services (services which either set exported=true or contain an intent-filter and do not specify exported=false) should define a permission that an entity must have in order to launch the service or bind to it. Without this, any application can use this service.

Should I just add this attribute to each service tag and be done with it

```
tools:ignore="ExportedService"
```

or is there a better approach in this situation? I mean, is it safe to expose these particular Firebase derived services like this?

Comment: If setting exported=true, the linter wants a permission defined. I'd like to see a complete answer that touches on this as well!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You ask:  *...is it safe to expose these particular Firebase derived services like this?*  It is if you trust the comments in the manifest files for these services.

In Android Studio, open your app's AndroidManifest.xml file.  At the bottom of the window, select the tab for *Merged Manifest*.  Scroll to find the entry for `FirebaseMessagingService`.  Double-click on the line that contains the service name.  The manifest file for the service should open and you will see this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.google.firebase.messaging">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>

    <application>

        <!-- FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true" -->
        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Note the comment: *FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime, no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"*

You can do the same for `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and see the same comment.

If you trust the comments (I do), you can safely ignore the lint warnings or disable the checks.

Comment: I did not know about the "Merged Manifest" button! Thank you!

Comment: We are setting `android:exported="false"` and I am still getting notifications.
Not sure if firebase really need them to be exported.

Comment: Is there any actual explanation to justify these comments? You might trust it, but why should we?

Comment: `FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime, but set to not exported to explicitly avoid allowing another app to call it.` That's what the comment stands for today.

Answer (score 7):

```
<service android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Based on the official code sample, it's safe to set exported=false